# Notepad++ Regex search for IP with special character

Tags: notepad++, search, regex

I'm trying to create a macro in Notepad++ to find IP addresses which include a `%` symbol.

So, I am trying to find IP addresses that meet this criteria:

```
10.x.x.x%2
```

That's it, I have tried many different regex variations and can find the IPs without issue, but I cannot seem to append `%2` to the search; every way I have tried even with ASCII codes fails.

I have to iterate through all the `10.x.x.x%2` and change them to `%1`. 
The gotcha is that I have a bunch of `10.x.x.x%1`'s in the same file and need those to remain.

By the way, this is a configuration from an F5 device, and the `%` symbol is how we distinguish different route domains.

Comment: What regex did you try? `10\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+%2` works for me in Notepad++ without problems...

Comment: That didn't work for me in version 7.3.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(10(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})%2`
- Replace with: `$1%1`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(               : start group 1
  10            : literally 10
  (?:           : start non capture group
    \.\d{1,3}   : a dot followed by 1 to 3 digits
  ){3}          : group must appear 3 times
)               : end group 1
%2              : literally %2
```

- *Check regular expression*
- *DO NOT CHECK `. matches newline`*

**Replacement:**

```
$1      : content of group 1
%1      : literally %1
```

---

I've assumed there are only IP addresses in each line. If you want to match specifically IP addresses, remplace `(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})` with `(?:\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)){3})` so:

- Find what: `(10(?:\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)){3})%2`
- Replace with: `$1%1`